How to Implement IAP Subscription Base Plan with Upgrade and Downgrade Features in Flutter?
Here are my requirements:

Users should be able to subscribe to a base plan.

Users should have the option to upgrade or downgrade their subscription to different tiers.


I have a few specific questions:

How can I set up subscription base plans with upgrade and downgrade options using the in_app_purchase plugin?

What is the best way to handle the logic for upgrading and downgrading subscriptions within the app?

How to get base plan id when user upgrade-downgrade as I'm not getting base plan ID in response


I used package example code to implement but i didnt find the details of base subscription plan
